# Python strip from multiple strings

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I have list of amazon ip address which are formatted like "ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compu" and like this "ip-x-x-x-x.ec2.internal".
I want to strip ".ap-southeast-1.compu" and ".ec2.internal" from ip address. I want to have ip address only (like ip-x-x-x-x). I have tried rstrip but I am not finding way of giving multiple strings for rstrip. It should strip ip address if it finds ".ap-southeast-1.compu" or ".ec2.internal".

Please Let me know how this can be handled in python.

Comment: could you iterate through your list and strip each one?

Comment: Do you mean that you want everything up to the first `'.'` character?

Comment: Thanks for reply.  @khelwood : Yes I want everything up to the first '.' character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string `split` function to split by dot char:

```
>>> ip = "ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compu"
>>> ip.split('.')[0]
'ip-x-x-x-x'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly.Just one thing, what does [0] at end in split does.?

Comment: @user2798042 `split('.')` divides up the string into pieces at the positions of the dots. To take the first piece only, you use `[0]`.

Comment: Just limit the split by 1,
``>>> ip.split('.', 1)[0]``

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most efficient way but I am a regular expression fan so figured I would show how to do it that way.

```
import re
NewIPs = []
regex = re.compile('(ip-\d*-\d*-\d*-\d*)')
for ip in IPList:
    NewIps.append(regex.search(ip).group(1))
```

That will go through your list of ips and fill a new list with the ips minus the endings.